# How to Avoid to Display Unicode Characters as Question Mark?

Tags: php, mysql, unicode

In my Table Creation I using Following Attributes

[image]

After Insert a Record It's Display in Phpmyadmin

[image]

Fetch Record in Frontend. Unicode Character as display Question Marks. How to solve It?

Comment: Which column has the question marks?

Comment: shot_desc and long_desc

Comment: `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%';`  `SELECT col, hex(col) FROM tbl...` -- to see what was actually stored.

Comment: What is your "frontend"?  It seems to not be connecting with utf8.

Answer (score 0):

Set a PHP header:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

You may also need to set a metatag in HTML:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I Already Put this Code. But Display ?????